# "NameError: name 'L_R' is not defined" using GPIO.PWM inside a Class

Tags: gpio, pwm, python-2.x

I'm trying to create a class to define various led status using 3 leds. For some status only I need to use GPIO.output method, but in other cases I want to use GPIO.PWM method to create a blink effect on the leds.

I spent about three hours but I can't discover the trouble, the code is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

LED_RED = 11
LED_GREEN = 7
LED_YELLOW = 12

LEDS = [LED_RED, LED_GREEN, LED_YELLOW]


##################################################################################
##                          LEDS STATUS DEFINITIONS                             ##
##################################################################################
##       STATUS       ##  LED RED  ##  LED GREEN  ##  LED YELLOW  ##  FUNCTION  ##
##################################################################################
## 'ON'               ##     1     ##      0      ##       0      ##   OUTPUT   ##
## 'FORWARD'          ##     1     ##      0      ##       1      ##   OUTPUT   ## 
## 'BACKWARD'         ##     1     ##      1      ##       0      ##   OUTPUT   ##
## 'MECH. BRAKE'      ##     1     ##      1      ##       1      ##   OUTPUT   ##
## 'INERTIAL BRAKE'   ##     1     ##    1(0.5)   ##    1(0.5)    ##    PWM     ##
## 'OVER CURRENT A'   ##     1     ##      1      ##    1(0.5)    ##    PWM     ## 
## 'OVER CURRENT B'   ##     1     ##    1(0.5)   ##       1      ##    PWM     ##
## 'LOSS CONNECTION'  ##   1(0.5)  ##    1(0.5)   ##    1(0.5)    ##    PWM     ##
################################################################################## 

STATUS = {'ON': (1, 0, 0), 'FORWARD': (1, 0, 1), 'BACKWARD': (1, 1, 0), 'M_BRAKE': (1, 1, 1), 'I_BRAKE': (0,2,2), 'OC_A': (0, 0, 2), 'OC_B': (2, 2, 2)}

DC = 50


class LedStatus():
    global STATUS, LEDS, DC

    def __init__(self):
        self.STATUS = STATUS
        self.LEDS = LEDS
        self.setup_pins()

    def on(self):
        print("[INFO]: Led Status ON")
        for i in range(len(LEDS)):
            GPIO.output(LEDS[i], STATUS['ON'][i])

    def forward(self):
        print("[INFO]: Led Status FORWARD")
        for i in range(len(LEDS)):
            GPIO.output(LEDS[i], STATUS['FORWARD'][i])

    def backward(self):
        print("[INFO]: Led Status BACKWARD")
        for i in range(len(LEDS)):
            GPIO.output(LEDS[i], STATUS['BACKWARD'][i])

    def m_brake(self):
        print("[INFO]: Led Status M_BRAKE")
        for i in range(len(LEDS)):
            GPIO.output(LEDS[i], STATUS['M_BRAKE'][i])

    def i_brake(self):
        print("[INFO]: Led Status I_BRAKE")
        L_R = GPIO.PWM(LEDS[0], STATUS['M_BRAKE'][0])
        L_R.start(DC)
        L_G = GPIO.PWM(LEDS[1], STATUS['M_BRAKE'][1])
        L_G.start(DC)
        L_Y = GPIO.PWM(LEDS[2], STATUS['M_BRAKE'][2])
        L_Y.start(DC)       

    def ocurrent_a(self):
        print("[INFO]: Led Status OVER CURRENT MOTOR A - OC_A")
        L_R = GPIO.PWM(LEDS[0], STATUS['OC_A'][0])
        L_R.start(DC)
        L_G = GPIO.PWM(LEDS[1], STATUS['OC_A'][1])
        L_G.start(DC)
        L_Y = GPIO.PWM(LEDS[2], STATUS['OC_A'][2])
        L_Y.start(DC)

    def ocurrent_b(self):
        print("[INFO]: Led Status OVER CURRENT MOTOR B - OC_B")
        L_R = GPIO.PWM(LEDS[0], STATUS['OC_B'][0])
        L_R.start(DC)
        L_G = GPIO.PWM(LEDS[1], STATUS['OC_B'][1])
        L_G.start(DC)
        L_Y = GPIO.PWM(LEDS[2], STATUS['OC_B'][2])
        L_Y.start(DC)

    def setup_pins(self):
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
        GPIO.setwarnings(False)
        for i in range(len(LEDS)):
            GPIO.setup(LEDS[i], GPIO.OUT)
        print("[INFO]: Pines {}, {} y {}, seteados como salidas").format(LEDS[0], LEDS[1], LEDS[2])


def test():
    status = LedStatus()
    status.on()
    time.sleep(5)
    status.forward()
    time.sleep(5)
    status.backward()
    time.sleep(5)
    status.m_brake()
    time.sleep(5)
    status.i_brake()
    time.sleep(5)
    status.ocurrent_a()
    time.sleep(5)
    status.ocurrent_b()
    time.sleep(5)
    status.on()

test()
```

The returned error is the follow:

```
L_R.start(DC)
NameError: name 'L_R' is not defined
```

I accept any kind of help or comments about the code, greetings and thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I discover that the problem it was not the code. The problem was an indentantion error imperceptible in Sublime Text. I only can see this problem opening the code with nano editor. The solution was select all the code (ctrl+a) and then click on the "Tab Size:" message on the right-bottom corner of Sublime Text interface and select "Convert indentation to tabs" option.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022018/how-to-debug-indentation-errors-in-python